# Setting parent.env, followed by `detach`, segfaults

Tags: r, environment

The following code reproducibly segfaults when executed in R (3.0.2 but I’m assuming it’s similar for other versions):

```
ns = new.env(parent = .BaseNamespaceEnv)
local(f <- function () 42, envir = ns)
x = list2env(as.list(ns), parent = as.environment(2))
parent.env(.GlobalEnv) = x
detach()
```

Yes, I know that the [documentation on `parent.env`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/environment.html) says

> The replacement function `parent.env<-` is extremely dangerous as it can be used to destructively change environments in ways that violate assumptions made by the internal C code. It may be removed in the near future.

That’s what I seem to be running into here. However, I would like to understand **why** this behaviour is the way it is, and how to avoid it.

The following simplified code does **not** have this problem:

```
x = new.env(parent = as.environment(2))
local(f <- function () 42, envir = x)
parent.env(.GlobalEnv) = x
detach()
```

… so it seems that it makes a difference that `x` contains a function whose `parent.env` is a *different* (unattached) environment.

Likewise, using `attach` instead of `parent.env<-` does not lead to a crash. (So why not simply use `attach`? Because in my code, the `.GlobalEnv` part is a variable which may refer to different environments.)

The crash dump tells me that the segfault happens in `do_detach` (`envir.c`). The code contains the following lines:

```
isSpecial = IS_USER_DATABASE(s);
if(isSpecial) {
    R_ObjectTable *tb = (R_ObjectTable*) R_ExternalPtrAddr(HASHTAB(s));
    if(tb->onDetach) tb->onDetach(tb);
}
```

I have no idea what `IS_USER_DATABASE` does – maybe this is related? Merely adding an `.onDetach` method to my environment (`.onDetach = function (x) x`) did not help.

Comment: I think you'd have to ask on r-devel.  Messing around with the parent  of globalenv seems like a _really_ bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Note: this is more of a comment than a real answer, but can't fit it in the comment field.  I have a **[loosely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366958/detaching-and-re-attaching-toolsrstudio)** and have been trying to better understand the limitations of `parent.env<-`.

In your case, note that the problem is actually related to `list2env`, not the function.  Consider:

```
f.1 <- function() NULL
ns.1 <- new.env(parent = .BaseNamespaceEnv)
x.1 <- new.env(parent = as.environment(2))
environment(f.1) <- ns.1
x.1$f.1 <- f.1
parent.env(.GlobalEnv) <- x.1
detach()
```

Works, but:

```
x.2 <- list2env(list(a=1), parent=as.environment(2))
parent.env(.GlobalEnv) <- x.2
detach()
```

crashes. Here, we are not even doing anything complex at all with the environment we're using as a parent, other than it was created with `list2env`.  Looking at the source I don't see anything obvious as to why `list2env` is a problem but `$<-` is not since both internally seem to use `defineVar`, but clearly there is a lot going on there that I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness’ sake, the obvious workaround is to test whether the environment is `.GlobalEnv`, and to special-case it:

```
new_env = something # e.g. .GlobalEnv

if (identical(new_env, .GlobalEnv))
    attach(x)
else {
    parent.env(x) = parent.env(new_env)
    parent.env(new_env) = x
}
```

… but this doesn’t *explain* the initial bug and, I fear, only hides the problem rather than removing it.