# Detaching and re-attaching "tools:rstudio"

Tags: r, search, rstudio, environment

a.k.a playing with fire...

The following does not work:

```
rstd.obj <- as.environment("tools:rstudio")
detach("tools:rstudio")
attach(rstd.obj, name="tools:rstudio")
```

Well, it seems to work, but then all sorts of weird errors start popping up.  The problem is that very annoyingly (though I'm sure for a very good reason) `attach` makes a copy of the environment and attaches that, instead of attaching the environment directly:

```
rstd.obj
# <environment: 0x000000000930edd0>
# attr(,"name")
# [1] "tools:rstudio"
as.environment("tools:rstudio")
# <environment: 0x000000000a21b4c8>
# attr(,"name")
# [1] "tools:rstudio"
```

Notice how the environments are actually different (this is also confirmed if you look at the source code for `do_attach` in `src/main/envir.c@2124(R3.0.2)` where the copy is made).

This, however, works totally fine (after restarting RStudio to reset everything):

```
rstd.obj <- as.environment("tools:rstudio")
rstd.parent <- as.environment("package:stats")  # this was #3 on search path for me
detach("tools:rstudio")

# WARNING: YOU'RE PLAYING WITH FIRE IF YOU RUN THIS, DO
# SO AT YOUR OWN RISK:

parent.env(.GlobalEnv) <- rstd.obj
parent.env(rstd.obj) <- rstd.parent
```

Instead of using `detach`/`attach`, we just `detach`, and forcibly insert the object back into the search path using `parent.env<-`.  On the flipside, I'm guessing doing the above is probably close to what R Core had in mind when they warned in `?parent.env`:

> The replacement function `parent.env<-` is extremely dangerous as it can be used to destructively change environments in ways that violate assumptions made by the internal C code. It may be removed in the near future.

Another alternative to get around this problem is to use `detach`/`attach`, but then cycle through all the functions in the `tools:rstudio` environment on the search path and reset their environments to the copy of the original environment now on the search path (incidentally, this is why Rstudio starts breaking: the function environments are still the object removed from the search path, but that environment is not in the search path anymore, only a copy of it).  This feels incredibly hacky though.

Also, if anyone knows more details about what the "assumptions made by the internal C code" are I'd be very interested to hear them.  Obviously, we could introduce circularities in the search path (no, I didn't accidentally just do that messing around with these examples...), but are there other problems as well?

EDIT: regarding the above, super useful tidbit from **[R-devel](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Making-parent-env-lt-an-error-for-package-namespaces-and-package-imports-td4698432.html)**:

> I'd like to propose a change to the R language so that calling
>   'parent.env<-' on a package namespace or package imports is a runtime
>   error. 
>   ...
>   I'd also like to make calling parent.env<- on an environment on the
>   call stack an error, for the same reasons, but it's not so obvious to
>   me how to implement that efficiently right now.  Could we at least
>   document that as being 'undefined behaviour'?

And Luke Tierney's answer:

> I'll look into it

This seems to confirm the concern is changing the call stack in call or search path in a way R may not track, as opposed to generally thinking `parent.env<-` is dangerous for other environment chains (clearly reading b/w lines here).

Comment: yow.  What are you trying to accomplish??

Comment: @BenBolker, I'm trying to automatically create a clean environment by resetting the search path to be bare bones (i.e. ending at `package:stats`), but having the ability to undo that change, which unfortunately requires being able to re-attach `tools:rstudio`.

Comment: have you looked into whatever machinery underlies the "Restart R" button in RStudio?  It looks like it's `.rs.restartR`, which has an `afterRestartCommand` option too ...

Comment: @BenBolker, interesting option.  One problem is this will not address other environments that are not automatically attached on start-up like "tools:rstudio" is.  I'd like a way of doing this that can restore the full state of the search path, irrespective of what it was beforehand.  Also, this should work on non RStudio environments so I may not be able to rely on those hooks (**[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313079/quit-and-restart-a-clean-r-session-from-within-r)** might be an option for the last point).